How would I transfer a modded app's data without losing my progress in game from an unrooted phone to another?
As the title says, I'd like to transfer a modded game's data from one phone (A50) to another (S23FE) and neither are rooted, but I'd be open to rooting my older phone if it could help and/or temporarily rooting the newer one if that's possible. I'm a bit new to all this but I've been soaking up information for hours on data transfer using adb, but haven't found a concrete answer. Sadly, I can't back up this game on a cloud unlike some other modded apps I have, so any suggestions is welcome. Thanks :)

If you have modded the APK you have resigned it before installing it. Do you still have the signing key? Has the modded APK debuggable=true in it's AndroidManifest.xml?
